# Problem to trasnform date from string to long in nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

I have some problems with transform date from string to long in NIFI. I have date like this: "02-01-1968|" and I need to transform this to long. i am using UpdateAttribte Processor to format it to number like this: ${my_date:toDate("dd-MM-yyyy","GMT"):toNumber()})} but I have result like this: "my_date" : -63072000000 .Does anyone know how to solve this better?